# How to set default color for ColorPicker in FXML

Tags: java, fxml

Is it possible to set the default color of a ColorPicker in FXML, or do I have to set the color in the FXML controllers initialize method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by using the `<value>` tag along with the `<Color>` tag, and an import for the Color type. This is briefly mentioned in the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), but without a full example.

Note SceneBuilder doesn't not appear to support editing of this. However SceneBuilder is non-destructive, in that you can open a file with a nested `<value>`, make changes, and `<value>` will be preserved.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<ColorPicker 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <value>
        <Color blue="0.0" green="0.0" red="1.0" />
    </value>
</ColorPicker>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Cannot create instance of javafx.scene.paint.Color with given set of properties: [red, green, blue]